# Plot count of entries per time range

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given Situation:
For a theroretical user study, participant's behaviour in a game is logged. 
We save *when* exactly they *score* points and want to observe how they perform over the course of the runtime.
Points are made up of "+1" for correct answer, "0" for skipped question and "-1" for wrong answer.

I started with this table:

```
   ParticipantID        Modus Timestamp Duration Point
1             70 Singleplayer      0.03     2.26     1
2             70 Singleplayer      0.53     2.26     1
3             70 Singleplayer      3.36     9.41    -1
4             70 Singleplayer     13.83     2.36     0
5             70 Singleplayer     17.25     8.71     1
6             70 Singleplayer     27.02     6.91     1
7             70 Singleplayer     35.00     3.22     1
8             70 Singleplayer     39.29     2.56     0
9             70 Singleplayer     42.91     6.51     1
10            70 Singleplayer     50.49     3.72     1
11            70 Singleplayer     55.25     2.96     1
12            71 Singleplayer      0.03     2.26     1
13            71 Singleplayer      3.38     9.41    -1
14            71 Singleplayer     13.20     2.36     0
15            71 Singleplayer     17.25     8.71     1
16            71 Singleplayer     27.02     6.91     1
17            71 Singleplayer     37.00     3.22     1
18            71 Singleplayer     39.29     2.56     0
19            71 Singleplayer     39.89     2.56     0
20            71 Singleplayer     42.91     6.51     1
21            71 Singleplayer     50.49     3.72     1
22            71 Singleplayer     55.25     2.96     1
```

Using these commands...

```
df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\AUser\\Documents\\DummyTestValues.csv")
dt <- as.data.table(df)
df$timeRange <- cut(df$Timestamp, breaks = c(seq(0,120,by=1)))
```

I grouped my time slots together in given ranges and reached this point:

```
   ParticipantID        Modus Timestamp Duration Point timeRange
1             70 Singleplayer      0.03     2.26     1     (0,1]
2             70 Singleplayer      0.53     2.26     1     (0,1]
3             70 Singleplayer      3.36     9.41    -1     (3,4]
4             70 Singleplayer     13.83     2.36     0   (13,14]
5             70 Singleplayer     17.25     8.71     1   (17,18]
6             70 Singleplayer     27.02     6.91     1   (27,28]
7             70 Singleplayer     35.00     3.22     1   (34,35]
8             70 Singleplayer     39.29     2.56     0   (39,40]
9             70 Singleplayer     42.91     6.51     1   (42,43]
10            70 Singleplayer     50.49     3.72     1   (50,51]
11            70 Singleplayer     55.25     2.96     1   (55,56]
12            71 Singleplayer      0.03     2.26     1     (0,1]
13            71 Singleplayer      3.38     9.41    -1     (3,4]
14            71 Singleplayer     13.20     2.36     0   (13,14]
15            71 Singleplayer     17.25     8.71     1   (17,18]
16            71 Singleplayer     27.02     6.91     1   (27,28]
17            71 Singleplayer     37.00     3.22     1   (36,37]
18            71 Singleplayer     39.29     2.56     0   (39,40]
19            71 Singleplayer     39.89     2.56     0   (39,40]
20            71 Singleplayer     42.91     6.51     1   (42,43]
21            71 Singleplayer     50.49     3.72     1   (50,51]
```

What I want to achieve now is a plot, that goes through the entire time range on the x-Axis and shows how many positive points were scored by each player during each time range.

(Example: Player 70 made two positive points between 0-1 seconds, and so forth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate( x = floor( Timestamp ) ) %>%
  group_by(ParticipantID, x) %>%
  summarise( score = sum( Point ) ) %>%
  ggplot( ., aes( x = x, y = score, group = as.factor(ParticipantID), color = as.factor(ParticipantID) ) ) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous( breaks = seq(0,120,5), labels = paste0(seq(0,120,5),"-", seq(1,121,5)),
                        minor_breaks = seq(0,120,1) ) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]